# BST O(NLogN) build proof

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to study for a test and I know that a single insertion is O(logn) and the height of the tree is n, so the comparisons would make the time  Ω(n log n).

How can I prove that, given an unsorted array A of n elements, the time required to build a BST is Ω(n log n) in the worst case.

Comment: You can't prove it because it's not true.

Comment: In the worst case, the tree grows as a long string that looks like a linked list where each node is added at the end. Building this requires time proportional to n^2. Saying the list is unsorted isn't good enough to avoid this. You can prove that _on average_ building a simple BST needs O(n log n) comparisons. And you can prove that a self-balancing tree like an AVL or Red-Black tree can be built with O(n log n) comparisons.  But the proofs aren't very simple.

Comment: can you tell me that if array is unsortd how would it get worst-case.?

Comment: Don't use Omega and Big-O interchangeably , they are two different things.

Comment: @Gene why do you think so? Building a balanced BST from any BST can be done in linear time, but this is not related to the question. Also if you have a sorted array you can easily build a BST from it.

Answer (score 3):

Traversing a BST can be done in linear time, so if you can build a BST from unsorted array 'faster' than O(n * log(n)) this would mean you can sort a unsorted array faster than O(n * log(n)) and we know [this can't be done](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sorting-algorithms/) unless you have additional information about the elements being sorted.

On the other hand you can sort the array in Ω(n*log(n)) and building a BST from a sorted array can be done in linear time(for instance build a 'list-like' tree).